# Converting a .jks file programmatically

Tags: android, security, jks

One of the main features of my application is to store user's keys on user's phone.  The keys can be produced by different CA in different formats (.p12, .pfx, .jks, .pem and .cer files, etc).

To simplify work with the key I convert it to PKCS12 format and store in the secure storage of application. Now, I start to implement converter (to PKCS12 format) for keys in JKS file and have a problem - Android does not support KeyStrore with type "JKS".

**Does anyone know how can I add security provider with JKS KeyStore support to my android application?**

I can't convert the key file to another format outside of the application, because application users don't familiar with cryptography. They just get's file in CA and import it to the application.

Comment: I think bouncycastle / spongycastle can help you

Comment: Of course I use spongycastle in my applications. But it doesn't support JKS format, only BKS, which is incompatible with JKS.

Comment: Ah, right I remember, you need to convert jks to bks offline with desktop java which has access to both. Seems to be primarily a legal issue due to Sun/Oracle copyrights. But maybe http://metastatic.org/source/JKS.html can achieve your goal

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839303/specification-of-jks-key-store-format

Comment: @zapl Thanks a lot, this realization http://metastatic.org/source/JKS.html really helped me.